# Access VBA Function doesn't return any value on query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have the following Access VBA Module (which returns info as needed as i tested it via Debug.Print), i then use it the following way in the SQL code.

```
Public Function DayInterval(DueDate As String) As String
Dim Today As Date
Dim ConvertData As Date

Today = Date
ConvertDate = DateSerial(Year(DueDate), Month(DueDate), Day(DueDate))

Select Case DateDiff("d", ConvertDate, Today)
    Case 1 To 10
      DueDate = "0-10"
    Case 11 To 30
      DueDate = "11-30"
    Case 31 To 60
      DueDate = "31-60"
    Case 61 To 90
      DueDate = "61-90"
   Case 91 To 180
      DueDate = "91-180"
   Case 181 To 365
      DueDate = "181-365"
   Case 366 To 540
      DueDate = "366-540"
   Case 541 To 730
      DueDate = "541-730"
   Case Else
      DueDate = ">730"
End Select

DayInterval = DueDate 

End Function

SELECT 
DueDate AS [Date], 
DayInterval([DUE_DATE]) AS [Interval]
FROM Invoices;
```

The problem is that when i run the above query, i get no results.

[image]

Any light on why this happens?

Thank you.

Comment: `IntervaloDias` vs `DayInterval`... Is this in your code or just an error putting the question up?

Comment: An error. Already corrected it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a true date value:

```
ConvertDate = DateSerial(Year(DateValue(DueDate)), Month(DateValue(DueDate)), Day(DateValue(DueDate)))
```

Or just (see Minty's comment):

```
ConvertDate = DateValue(DueDate)
```

Comment: DateValue(DueDate) would return a date in the same local regional settings, intrigued as to why would you use Date Serial?

Comment: It was to keep the style - and we might only see a snippet. But you are right, as is, DateSerial here is superfluous.

Comment: Both work (and thanks for the feedback), but my problem is not getting any results when running the function in SQL code, because no results appear.

Comment: Already solved it. I was missing this at the end of the function: DayInterval = DueDate